# Check if index in list meets criteria

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to figure out if any index of a list of data does not meet the criteria I have. I imagine that I would have to use the `np.where` function but I don't know how I would match each index to see if it meets or does not meet the criteria. I need to make sure that the data is within certain values.

For example, the condition is `1.5 < x < 4.9` so how would I check if anywhere in a list, it does not meet the condition?

Comment: `(a < 4.9)&(a>1.5)` yields `True` where it meets the conditions. `((a < 4.9)&(a>1.5)).any()` yields `True` if, as you asked, *anywhere in a list it does not meet the condition*.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
((1.5 <= x) | (x >= 4.9)).any()
```

Comment: Use `~` not `not` if you're negating a result with `numpy`

Comment: The `not` was acting on a single `bool_` in which case it is equivalent to `~`.